# Translate C# to Powershell

Tags: c#, powershell, selenium

I'm trying to setup Firefox WebDrvier to automate the navigation with PowerShell. I can launch it using:

```
# Load the Selenium .Net library
Add-Type -Path "net40\WebDriver.dll"

# Set the PATH to ensure geckodriver.exe can found
$env:PATH += ";E:\*****\FirefoxDriver"

$driver = New-Object OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox.FirefoxDriver
```

But I need to use the service "FirefoxDriver**Service**". I found this C# code  [on the Internet](http://automatedtester.science/marionette-geckodriver/).

```
FirefoxDriverService service = FirefoxDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
service.FirefoxBinaryPath = @"C:\Path\to\your\FF\exe.exe";
FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
options.AddAdditionalCapability(CapabilityType.AcceptSslCertificates, true);
TimeSpan t = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);

Driver = new FirefoxDriver(service, options, t);
```

I tried some experiments (in PowerShell):

**1**

```
[FirefoxDriverService]$service = $FirefoxDriverService.CreateDefaultService()
```

But Powershell said this to me:

```
 You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
```

**2**

```
$driver = New-Object OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox.FirefoxDriver(service FirefoxDriverService)
```

But Powershell said this to me:

```
 No Service Found For Given Name
```

I am a sysadmin not a developer, so I have no more ideas.

Here is the [doc about the webdriver for Firefox](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/N_OpenQA_Selenium_Firefox.htm).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`CreateDefaultService()`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/M_OpenQA_Selenium_Firefox_FirefoxDriverService_CreateDefaultService_2.htm) is a static method, use the static member operator `::`:

```
$Service = [OpenQA.Selenium.FirefoxFirefoxDriverService]::CreateDefaultService()
```